# Flip-Flop with enable with a single cycle enable signal

Tags: vhdl

I have a flip-flop that I need to enable for only one clock cycle. What is the standard practice for single-cycle enable signal in these kind of situations?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yesterday there was an nice answer with pseudo code from Oli Charlesworth, but that is missing today.  Unless the below code is the answer to you question, could you please elaborate on what you mean by "enable for only one clock cycle".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flip-flop that is only enabled a single cycle after reset is shown below; all signals are std_logic:

```
process (clk, rst) is
begin
  if rst = '1' then
    fired <= '0';
  elsif rising_edge(clk) then
    if fired = '0' then
      q     <= d;
      fired <= '1';
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

Comment: Thank you Morten. I also found another solution. We can define a signal which : S_fireed <= fired; if(s_fired = '0' and fired = '1') the q <= d just for one clock cycle even if signal fired stays = '1' more than one clock cycle.